# Type casting to String representation of a class in Java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, abstract-class

I want to cast an object to one of a few different types that comes to me in the form of a string. I know the casting will work out but I haven't managed to work out how to address this:

```
Tools a = new Loader(); //Loader extends the Tools abstract class
String cl = "Loader";
Loader b = (cl) a; //Obviously this doesn't work
Loader b = (Loader) a; //This is the effect I want, but from a String repr. of Loader
```

How can I convert this string so that this type casting works out? I have tried `Class.forName()` without good results:

```
Loader b = (Class.forName(cl)) a;
```

...but I get complaints about `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture-#1-of ?> to Loader`

Also, as an extension of this question, do I need to cast the object to a type first or will I be able to use it as an on-the-fly casting inside a method invocation or so, something like this:

```
doSomething(("Loader") b); //Assuming doSomething requires a Loader type...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work for you.

```
String c1 = "Loader";
Class c = Class.forName(c1);
Loader b = (c)a;
```

Comment: No, It doesn't work :( Try to compile something similar yourself... the compiler complains about missing symbols... According to other threads, you have to make an explicit castingin the compiler becuase otherwise the compiler don't know what fields and methods the casted object will have...